# Splitting a column into multiple columns based on 2 conditions

Tags: r, split

I have a large dataframe and I would like to split a column into many columns based on two conditions the caret character ^ and the letter following IMM-. Based on the data below Column 1 would be split into columns named IMM-A, IMM-B, IMM-C, and IMM-W. I tried the separate function but it only works if you specify the column names and because my data is not uniform I don't always know what the column names should be.

```
SampleId  Column1
1         IMM-A*010306+IMM-A*0209^IMM-B*6900+IMM-B*779999^IMM-C*1212+IMM-C*3333
2         IMM-A*010306+IMM-A*0209^IMM-C*6900+IMM-C*779999^IMM-W*1212+IMM-W*3333
3         IMM-B*010306+IMM-B*0209^IMM-C*6900+IMM-C*779999^IMM-W*1212+IMM-W*3333
```

The expected output would be;

```
SampleId    IMM-A                   IMM-B                   IMM-C                IMM-W
1           IMM-A*010306+IMM-A*0209 IMM-B*6900+IMM-B*779999 IMM-C*1212+IMM-C*3333
2           IMM-A*010306+IMM-A*0209                         IMM-C*6900+IMM-C*779999 IMM-W*1212+IMM-W*3333
3                                   IMM-B*010306+IMM-B*0209 IMM-C*6900+IMM-C*779999 IMM-W*1212+IMM-W*3333
```

Comment: Please see my edits

Comment: Thank you for updating the post.  I updated the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not clear about the expected output.  Based on the description, we may need

```
library(tidyverse)
map(strsplit(df$Column1, "[*+^]"), ~  
  stack(setNames(as.list(.x[c(FALSE, TRUE)]), .x[c(TRUE, FALSE)])) %>% 
  group_by(ind) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  spread(ind, values)) %>% 
  set_names(df$SampleId) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = 'SampleId') %>%
  select(-rn)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
#  SampleId `IMM-A` `IMM-B` `IMM-C` `IMM-W`
#  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#1 1        010306  6900    1212    <NA>   
#2 1        0209    779999  3333    <NA>   
#3 2        010306  <NA>    6900    1212   
#4 2        0209    <NA>    779999  3333   
#5 3        <NA>    010306  6900    1212   
#6 3        <NA>    0209    779999  3333
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's expected output, we expand the data by splitting the 'Column1' at the `^` delimiter, then `separate` the 'Column1' into 'colA', 'colB' at the delimiter `*`, remove the 'colB' and `spread` to 'wide' format

```
df %>% 
   separate_rows(Column1, sep = "\\^") %>% 
   separate(Column1, into = c("colA", "colB"), remove = FALSE, sep="[*]") %>% 
   select(-colB) %>% 
   spread(colA, Column1, fill = "")
#SampleId                   IMM-A                   IMM-B                   IMM-C                 IMM-W
#1        1 IMM-A*010306+IMM-A*0209 IMM-B*6900+IMM-B*779999   IMM-C*1212+IMM-C*3333                      
#2        2 IMM-A*010306+IMM-A*0209                         IMM-C*6900+IMM-C*779999 IMM-W*1212+IMM-W*3333
#3        3                         IMM-B*010306+IMM-B*0209 IMM-C*6900+IMM-C*779999 IMM-W*1212+IMM-W*3333
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(SampleId = 1:3, Column1 = 
  c("IMM-A*010306+IMM-A*0209^IMM-B*6900+IMM-B*779999^IMM-C*1212+IMM-C*3333", 
 "IMM-A*010306+IMM-A*0209^IMM-C*6900+IMM-C*779999^IMM-W*1212+IMM-W*3333", 
 "IMM-B*010306+IMM-B*0209^IMM-C*6900+IMM-C*779999^IMM-W*1212+IMM-W*3333"
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```